# vba with Excel internet explorer does not use newly opened tab fro getelemtsbytagname

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, dom, web-scraping

I have created VBA code inside Microsoft Excel.
What I want the code to do is:

1. Go to a site.
2. Click on a link on the site.
3. Go to the newly opened tab, and then click download on the new tab.
4. Then go back to the root/first page and click on the next and click download.
5. Repeat until all the root page links are clicked and downloaded.

I have the code below, that sort of works. It uses internet explorer as the site does not work well with google chrome though I would try that if that would work better.

The code does navigate, does open a tab... What this code does not do is start using the data from the new page/tab, all the elements are from the root page.  I tried making a new instance of IE, selecting by `item(1)`. I am not sure what I need to do to make the `instancehyperlinks` refer to the newly created tab.  FYI, the data comes up in a new tab because of the way the root site is written, I do not have control over any of the HTML.

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub getalllinks()

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    url_name = "123.123.123.123"
    ie.navigate url_name
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4 ' wait until fully loaded
    Set allhyperlinks = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("A")
    For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
        If hyper_link.Title = "View Subject" Then
            hyper_link.Click
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4 ' wait until fully loaded
            Set instancehyperlinks = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("A")
            For Each hyper_linkPage In instancehyperlinks
                If hyper_linkPage.Title = "Download" Then
                    hyper_linkPage.Click
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The site `123.123.123.123` is unreachable.

Comment: We cannot test the URL and there is no HTML to work with. I can't see any window finding code in the above either. I would suggest looking into selenium basic perhaps where it is fairly easy to locate tabs and switch.

Comment: Please share the root webpage HTML content. Or at least, add the line `Debug.Print hyper_link.outerHtml: Stop` right before `hyper_link.Click`, and share the output from immediate window. Check if there is the [attribute `target="_blank`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp), you may remove it, then click.

Comment: The web page is secure, I cannot access it without a username and password.  One I log in I can access it through VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've run into this problem before and solved it WITHOUT having to use any third part tools like selenium and before I get into the answer let me give you a piece of advice: automating IE with VBA is a severe PITA, if it ALL possible I would look into other avenues.

DISCLAIMER: a lot of this code I found and modified from other sources, for many reasons I cant track down the source's right now, if I find them I will add them later.

ok, first you need to find your window, make a new module and call it "modWindowsAPI" and add this into it, this will allow your script to hook into the necessary windows API's to not only find the windows but download as well:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Declare Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long

Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
Public Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE

Public Const VK_KEYDOWN = &H0
Public Const VK_KEYUP = &H2
Public Const VK_CONTROL = &H11
```

From here there are 2 ways of locking on to a window (that I know of, there may be more), finding it by URL or by window Title.

**Finding window by URL:**
Create function GetOpenIEByTitle:

```
Function GetOpenIEByTitle(i_Title As String, Optional ByVal i_ExactMatch As Boolean = True) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim windowMatched As Boolean
    Dim e_title As String
    windowMatched = False
    Dim windowTimeout As Integer
    windowTimeout = 0

    Do Until windowMatched = True Or windowTimeout = 10
        If i_ExactMatch = False Then i_Title = "*" & i_Title & "*"
        'ignore errors when accessing the document property
        On Error Resume Next
        'loop over all Shell-Windows
        For Each GetOpenIEByTitle In objShellWindows
            'if the document is of type HTMLDocument, it is an IE window
            If TypeName(GetOpenIEByTitle.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            'check the title
                If GetOpenIEByTitle.Document.Title Like i_Title Then
                    'leave and set boolean as true, we found the right window
                    windowMatched = True
                    Sleep 600
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
    windowTimeout = windowTimeout + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

**Finding window by URL:**
Create function named GetOpenIEByURL

```
Function GetOpenIEByURL(ByVal i_URL As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim urlMatched As Boolean
    urlMatched = False
    Dim urlTimeout As Integer
    urlTimeout = 0
    Do Until urlMatched = True Or urlTimeout = 30

        Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

        'ignore errors when accessing the document property
        On Error Resume Next
        'loop over all Shell-Windows
        For Each GetOpenIEByURL In objShellWindows
            'if the document is of type HTMLDocument, it is an IE window
            If TypeName(GetOpenIEByURL.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            'check the URL
                If GetOpenIEByURL.Document.URL = i_URL Then
                    'leave, we found the right window
                    urlMatched = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next

    urlTimeout = urlTimeout + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

**Wrap-Up**
You were on the right path with needing multiple IE objects, each active window will need its own object, you can reuse the same object if your closing it and going to the next one.

Call one of the above methods like below:

```
Set ieAppChild = GetOpenIEByTitle("Some Title", False)
Set ieAppChild = GetOpenIEByURL("https://127.0.0.1")
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention when your ready to close out an IE window to move onto the next one don't forget to call ieAppChild.Quit and you don't necessarily have to set the ie child objects to nothing before reuse, however, its not the best practice.

and finally the function to find the download window and click save:

```
Function SaveAs()
    Dim hWnd As Long

    Dim timeout As Date

    'Debug.Print "File_Download_Click_Save"

    'Find the File Download window, waiting a maximum of 30 seconds for it to appear

    timeout = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")

    Do
        hWnd = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download")
        DoEvents
        Sleep 200
    Loop Until hWnd Or Now > timeout

    'Debug.Print "   File Download window "; Hex(hWnd)
    If hWnd Then
        'Find the child Save button
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "Button", "&Save")
        'Debug.Print "   Save button "; Hex(hWnd)
    End If


    If hWnd Then

        'Click the Save button
        SetForegroundWindow (hWnd)
        Sleep 600  'this sleep is required and 600 miiliseconds seems to be the minimum that works
        SendMessage hWnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks user1090660 The way I resolved it was by making this a 2 step script, first I collect all the links from the first page into an excel sheet Shutdown internet explorer Then reopen internet explorer for each link in the excel sheet Then I am on the proper page and can mine the data. My way is not nearly as elegant or expandable as yours but it works, Thanks for your answer. Martin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user1090660
The way I resolved it was by making this a 2 step script, first I collect all the links from the first page into an excel sheet
Shutdown internet explorer
Then reopen internet explorer for each link in the excel sheet
Then I am on the proper page and can mine the data.
My way is not nearly as elegant or expandable as yours but it works,
Thanks for your answer.
Martin

Comment: Not sure that this was really necessary. You could store the links in a nodeList or a collection and loop over that. Use the existing IE instance and simply navigate onto the new link extracted from the current item (element) in the loop.

Comment: True, but you know how it is when you are not really sure how to solve a problem and start trying things.  The new sheet worked fine and I could read it so I just carried on....  Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Hi,  I didn't mean to sound rude. Sorry. It was meant as a helpful observation.

Comment: No Worries, I took it as helpful, Martin